# Minimizing the Frobenius norm with linear inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

How to solve the following system for $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{a}$:

$\min\|\mathbf{X-XC} \,\mbox{diag} (\mathbf{a})\|_F^2$ subject to $\mathbf{c}_{ik}\geq 0$, $1^T \mathbf{c}_k = 1$ and $1-\delta\leq\mathbf{a}_k\leq 1+\delta$

where $\delta$ is a small value, $\mathbf{c}_k$ is the kth column vector with nonnegative entries, $\mathbf{c}_{ik}$ is the ith element of vector $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{a}_k$ is the kth element of vector $\mathbf{a}$

Comment: What does $C \geq 1$ mean? Does it mean $c_{ij} \geq 1$ or $C \succeq I_n$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Apologies for mistake. vector $\mathbf{c}$ should have positive entries that sum to 1.

Comment: Then why not write $1_n^T c_k = 1$ and $c_k > 0$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, with respect to one variable the problem is convex. So we need to optimize alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

We have a convex **quadratic program**

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|A X - A\|_F^2\\ \text{subject to} & (1 - \delta) 1_n \leq X^T 1_n \leq (1 + \delta) 1_n\\ & X \geq 0\\ & X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\end{array}$$

Vectorizing $X$, this QP can be written in a more standard form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|(I_n \otimes A) \, \mbox{vec} (X) - \mbox{vec} (A)\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & (1 - \delta) 1_{n^2} \leq (I_n \otimes 1_n^T)\, \mbox{vec} (X) \leq (1 + \delta) 1_{n^2}\\ & \mbox{vec} (X) \geq 0\\ & \mbox{vec} (X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I want to estimate $A$ and the scale parameter $a$ separately, as I need them for some further operations. Can we go for something like gradient descent etc?

Comment: @VinayakAbrol If you want $X$ to be of the form $X = Y \mbox{diag} (w)$ where the entries in each column of $Y$ add to one, then choose the weight vector $w = X^T 1_n$. You can find $X$ using a QP solver. Once you have $X$ and $w$, then $Y = X  (\mbox{diag} (w))^{-1}$.

Comment: Apologies for mistake! As per your notation my unknowns are $X$ and $a$.

Comment: @VinayakAbrol Once one has $X$, finding $Y$ and $w$ is easy. Finding $X$ is easy, too. If you have MATLAB, use `quadprog`.